# CSS flexbox vertical scrollbar on 100% height columns in row FF/IE/EDGE

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building a html app that is loaded into a 3rd party app and is meant to fill the vertical and horizontal space provided to my app without causing page level scrollbars. To do this, I have made use of flexbox styles heavily, but I cannot find a solution to the following requirements that works on the latest versions of IE/EDGE and FF (Chrome works as expected).

Requirements:

- 2 column layout
- LHS column is 100% high of available space, and has a vertical scrollbar for when its contents are longer then the columns height.
- RHS column is 100% high and 100% width of available space (I have acheived this currently)
- LHS & RHS columns cannot have "position:absolute" styles (FF performance issues rendering HighCharts inside containers with flex and absolute positioning) or explicit pixel heights/widths (needs to be responsive).

I have setup this fiddle demonstrating the problem that is present in FF/IE/EDGE - page level scrollbars due to LHS content. Chrome is behaving as desired.

http://jsfiddle.net/jzo56zzg/

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div>
        SOME 3RD PARTY ELEMENTS HERE
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">
                <p>lots of content</p>
                <p>lots of content</p>
                // enough content to be higher then app's allowed height
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                right
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: yellow;
}

.row {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
}

.left {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: green;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  background: pink;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this relatively simple design (one would think) with the strict requirements mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle showing the result that I think you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/wjsqmsbs/

The trouble is that the ways in which heights are calculated can get a bit squirrelly. The key elements in my solution are:

```
.row:last-child {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and

```
.column {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```